# Change field name with regex in ElasticSearch metricbeat

Tags: elasticsearch, metricbeat

I'm using the metricbeat system with the graphite module.
This is the module configuration:

```
- module: graphite
  metricsets:
   - server
  protocol: "udp"
  port: 2003
  templates:
   - filter: "*" 
     namespace: "spark_metrics"
     template: "env.job_id.metric*"
     delimiter: "_"
```

Sometimes I get a metric with a number. The template looks like that:

```
env.job_id.number.metric*
```

I have no idea how to extract that. I also think I can't use the 'rename' processor because it seems there is no regex support. As I said the number is just sometimes there. If it is a specific executor metric then the executor number is being added. I want to extract the executor number to a new tag and I don't want it as part of the metric name.

[image]

As you can see the number of the executor is part of the field name. I want to extract it to look like this: `graphite.spark_metrics.tag.executor_number = 6`.

And the metric field look like: `graphite.spark_metrics.executor_filesystem_file_read_bytes = 0`

Does dose someone have any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe with the script processor ? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/processor-script.html

Comment: That is what I'm working on exactly now. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Do you know how can I find a filed/key name by a regex? I couldn't figure out how to do it with the event object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the script processor to solve the problem.
The fields that looks like `graphite.spark_metrics.10_memoryBlock = 2` will be split into 2 fields:

```
graphite.spark_metrics.memoryBlock = 2
graphite.spark_metrics.tag.executor = 10
```

And if the field looks like that: `graphite.spark_metrics.memoryBlock = 2` nothing will happen.

```
function process(event) {
  var metricPrefix = "graphite.spark_metrics";
  var excutorRegex = /^(\d*)_(.*)/;
  var metricObj = event.Get(metricPrefix)
  var keys = Object.keys(metricObj)

  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var found = keys[i].match(excutorRegex) // "10_memoryBlock" -> ["10_memoryBlock", "10", "memoryBlock"]
    if (found) {
      event.Put(metricPrefix + ".tag.executor", parseInt(found[1]))
      event.Rename(metricPrefix + "." + found[0], metricPrefix + "." + found[2])
      break;
    }
  }
}
```